# Is there a way to filter iOS Shortcuts photos by aspect ratio?

Tags: ios, ios-shortcut

Is there a way to filter iOS Shortcuts photos by aspect ratio?

I have a Shortcut that finds a random photo after the filter Favorite in the last 12 months is applied. I would like to only have vertically oriented photos but aspect ratio isn't an option. Width and Height are options but the filter doesn't appear to let me compare the two whereby the width is less than the height. Currently I'm using a hard coded less than width which won't work long term if photo resolutions change. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue:

I worked around this by getting 1 photo result, then using 'Get details of images' to set height and width to variables and comparing them in an if statement. If height bigger than width, set photo as wallpaper and end shortcut.

Wrapped the whole thing, including "Find photos" in "Repeat 20x" so it will iterate until it finds a match.